# EF5: prevent automatic column discovery

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I use EF's code-first and "fluent" APIs. It automatically maps my entities' properties and navigation properties.

I have lots of behavior and other properties in those classes, and so need to call `Ignore()` in such cases.

Can I change it so it only maps what I *explicitly* specify using the fluent API? I want to work on a whitelist approach, rather than its current blacklist approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible in EF5. You probably could do some hacking with reflection to configure all properties as Ignored and then overwrite configurations for properties you don't want to be ignored. Custom conventions are back in EF6 (http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/34668c5ce244)